# StructureMap Open Generics Use Based on Derived Type

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have two entity base classes:

```
public abstract class EntityBase { }
public abstract class ClientSpecificEntityBase : EntityBase
```

and two categories of entities:

```
public class Thing : EntityBase { }
public class ClientSpecificThing : ClientSpecificEntityBase { }
```

and two types of services, which both implement `IService<T>`

```
ServiceBase<T> : Service<T> where T : EntityBase
ClientSpecificServiceBase<T> : ServiceBase<T> where T : ClientSpecificEntityBase
```

I'm using the following code to configure StructureMap:

```
_.For(typeof(IService<>)).Use(typeof(ServiceBase<>));
_.For<IService<ClientSpecificEntityBase>>().Use<ClientSpecificServiceBase<ClientSpecificEntityBase>>();
```

But everytime I try to access `IService<ClientSpecificThing>`:

```
public ClientSpecificThingController(IService<ClientSpecificThing> service)
```

I am getting `ServiceBase<ClientSpecificThing>` rather than `ClientSpecificServiceBase<ClientSpecificThing>`

Is there any way to get StructureMap to include the derived types when it maps `ClientSpecificServiceBase<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do what you're trying to do. The container isn't going to look through the registered components for base classes of generic types.

This becomes more apparent if you remove the first registration, leaving only

```
_.For<IService<ClientSpecificEntityBase>>()
    .Use<ClientSpecificServiceBase<ClientSpecificEntityBase>>();
```

Now, if you call

```
var resolved = container.GetInstance<IService<ClientSpecificThing>>();
```

You'll get an exception:

> StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException: No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'IService'

So it's not that StructureMap is confused between the two registrations and is returning the wrong one. It doesn't recognize that when you register this:

```
IService<ClientSpecificEntityBase>
```

that it can use that fulfill this because one generic type inherits from the other.

```
IService<ClientSpecificThing>
```

Comment: Is there any way, except for manually mapping those derived types, to get ScructureMap to return the appropriate `IService`? I looked at a Factory, but the example I found uses `Activator.CreateInstance` which I couldn't make work since the `IServices` uses dependency injection too.

Comment: I switched to SimpleInjector in the end and was able to use these two lines: 

`container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IService<>), typeof(ClientSpecificServiceBase<>), c => typeof(ClientSpecificEntityBase).IsAssignableFrom(c.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments().Single()));

container.RegisterConditional(typeof(IService<>), typeof(ServiceBase<>), c => !c.Handled);`